# Equals override for nullable object

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a custom class that I would like to override Equals.  But it fails to work if the object calling it is null, for example

```
CustomClass? myCustomClass = null;
myCustomClass.Equals(some_object);
```

This gives me a warning that CustomClass may be null, and if executed, an exception is thown.

I can solve this issue by having an Extension method instead of overriding Equals, like so:

```
public static bool Equals(this CustomClass? customClass) { … }
```

This works well, but if the object I’m using isn’t nullable:

```
CustomClass myCustomClass = new();
myCustomClass.Equals(some_object);
```

…equals is handled by the default Object method and not my code

Surely they’re must be a solution to this?

Comment: How about you do `some_object.Equals(myCustomClass)` instead?

Comment: What about using the static `Equals()` method from `object` which takes two arguments? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0#system-object-equals(system-object-system-object)

Comment: Or maybe create a `IEqualityComparer` which takes two arguments

Comment: My main concern is how others may use this, I would like to define a class that is simple to use and acts as users would expect...

Comment: If you want to call `Equals` on a nullable reference you need to check for null and handle it.  Like `myCustomClass?.Equals(some_object) ?? some_object == null;` .

Answer (score 0):

If any of the objects is null, the comparison operation may not be logically correct.
Before checking that the references are equal, you can check with the HasValue property. Otherwise, it may throw a NullReferenceException. When overriding the Equals method in the Microsoft documentation, it provided the null check as follows (If the object is null, no comparison has been made.):

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
   {
      //Check for null and compare run-time types.
      if ((obj == null) || ! this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
      {
         return false;
      }
      else {
         Point p = (Point) obj;
         return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
      }
   }
```

You can examine the Point.cs class in the example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals

Comment: Surely it is valid to check of two objects (of the same type) are both null - i.e. Equal?!  This seems too difficult!

Comment: Yes, so when checking equals you should also check for null on the object. @BenRobinson